# Publish website, aspnet_compiler null reference exception

Tags: msbuild, aspnet-compiler

I'm having trouble publishing a solution through the command line.  It intermittently fails on various projects, but every so often succeeds.  I get both the null reference error and "The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded" which may just be the null reference with a race condition.  It seems to only fail on projects that have web services (original .asmx and WCF with .svc or file-less activation).  The fact that it sometimes succeeds makes me think it's not an issue with our code, though there may be some changes we can do to mitigate the underlying cause (whatever that may be).

What I tried/checked:

- I ran `tfpt scorch` to clean up any local changes including build output without success, so I know it's not an issue with the source directories.
- I cleared the temp files at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` (we're on 32-bit) and seemed to get further but still had issues.  After another publish the directory was still empty so probably unrelated.
- With Process Monitor I found `aspnet_compiler` was writing to `%LocalAppData%\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.  Clearing these files seems to sometimes work or maybe I got lucky, but then it starts failing again.  I didn't spot anything else that may be relevant.
- Make sure I have enough RAM, didn't seem to make a difference.
- Run msbuild single-threaded, no difference
- Run the aspnet_compiler from the command line (get command from the MSBuild log output), always succeeds
- There are no compressed folders
- I'm on the latest stable Visual Studio (VS 2013 update 2), but that shouldn't matter since I'm running from the command line and the executables used are in the framework directory.
- There is no App_Code folder in some of the failing projects

The build output doesn't give any good information so I set up DebugDiag to output on crash.  Here are the results:

```
DetailID = 1
    Count:    1
    Type:     System.NullReferenceException
    Message:  
    Stack:    
        System.Web.Compilation.DiskBuildResultCache.CacheBuildResult(System.String, System.Web.Compilation.BuildResult, Int64, System.DateTime)
        System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CacheBuildResultInternal(System.String, System.Web.Compilation.BuildResult, Int64, System.DateTime)
        System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.CacheAssemblyResults(System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults)
        System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.CompileAssemblyBuilder(System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder)
        System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.CompileAssemblyBuilderParallel(System.Collections.ICollection)
        System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.CompileNonDependentBuildProviders(System.Collections.ICollection)
        System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.Process()
        System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(System.Web.Hosting.VirtualDirectory, Boolean)
        System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(System.Web.Hosting.VirtualDirectory, System.Web.VirtualPath, Boolean)
        System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileWebDirectoriesRecursive(System.Web.Hosting.VirtualDirectory, Boolean)
        System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileAppInternal(System.Web.VirtualPath, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)
        System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileApp(System.Web.VirtualPath, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)
        System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileApp(System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManagerCallback, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)
        System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerHost.PrecompileApp(System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManagerCallback, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.String>)
        [GCFrame]
        [GCFrame]
        [ContextTransitionFrame]
        [GCFrame]
        [GCFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [TPMethodFrame]
        *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web\3d247ccfb800c38a29cf91c27a6339da\System.Web.ni.dll
        Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web\3d247ccfb800c38a29cf91c27a6339da\System.Web.ni.dll
        System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManagerCallback)
        *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe
        [GCFrame]


DetailID = 2
    Count:    1
    Type:     System.NullReferenceException
    Message:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Stack:    
        [GCFrame]
        [GCFrame]
        [GCFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [GCSafeCollectionFrame]
        [TPMethodFrame]
        System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManagerCallback, Boolean)
        System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManagerCallback)
        System.Web.Compilation.Precompiler.Main(System.String[])
        [GCFrame]
```

I have found others with similar issues but they were either unanswered or the solutions didn't work for me.  Any more ideas?

**Edit:**
This is the command line I'm using:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\MSBuild.exe" Solution.sln /t:Build /m:1 /p:Configuration=Prod /p:Platform="Mixed Platforms" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Prod /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false /v:diag > out.txt
```

Here is some of the console output (redirected to the file):

```
Target "AspNetPreCompile: (TargetId:3773)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets" from project "C:\Source\Project\Project.csproj" (target "PipelineAspNetCompileMergePhase" depends on it):
Task "AspNetCompiler" (TaskId:2474)
  Task Parameter:PhysicalPath=C:\Source\Project\obj\x86\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source (TaskId:2474)
  Task Parameter:TargetPath=C:\Source\Project\obj\x86\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir (TaskId:2474)
  Task Parameter:VirtualPath=/ (TaskId:2474)
  Task Parameter:Debug=False (TaskId:2474)
  Task Parameter:Updateable=False (TaskId:2474)
  Task Parameter:ToolPath=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 (TaskId:2474)

  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p C:\Source\Project\obj\x86\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source C:\Source\Project\obj\x86\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir  (TaskId:2474)
  Microsoft (R) ASP.NET Compilation Tool version 4.0.30319.34209 (TaskId:2474)
  Utility to precompile an ASP.NET application (TaskId:2474)
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. (TaskId:2474)
   (TaskId:2474)
ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [C:\Source\Project\Project.csproj]
  The command exited with code 1. (TaskId:2474)

Done executing task "AspNetCompiler" -- FAILED. (TaskId:2474)
Done building target "AspNetPreCompile" in project "Project.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:3773)
```

So as you can see, the msbuild diagnostic output isn't very helpful.

**Edit 2:**
Trying to see if I can debug `aspnet_compiler` to shed more light on this.  I kicked off `gflags.exe` to enable auto-attaching to the debugger.  I was able to break on the `NullReferenceException` but I'm having trouble loading the symbols for `System.Web`.  It's coming from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll`.

From the stack trace, it's failing in this method:

```
internal override void CacheBuildResult(string cacheKey, BuildResult result, long hashCode, DateTime utcStart)
{
  if (!result.CacheToDisk)
    return;
  if (HostingEnvironment.ShutdownInitiated)
  {
    BuildResultCompiledAssemblyBase compiledAssemblyBase = result as BuildResultCompiledAssemblyBase;
    if (compiledAssemblyBase == null)
      return;
    this.MarkAssemblyAndRelatedFilesForDeletion(compiledAssemblyBase.ResultAssembly.GetName().Name);
  }
  else
    new PreservationFileWriter(this.PrecompilationMode).SaveBuildResultToFile(this.GetPreservedDataFileName(cacheKey), result, hashCode);
}
```

So any of these could be null and causing the exception: `result`, `HostingEnvironment`, `compiledAssemblyBase`.

Comment: Share how you're launching this from the command line to include all arguments.  Also, create a diagnostic log for greater build output and refer to the log rather than the console output for detail.

Comment: @Nicodemeus: Edited my question to include more details.  Regarding the diagnostic log I assume you just meant `/v:diag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was to fix such issue, I would try to isolate it as much as possible, so here is the plan.

I see the following possible reasons:

1. Building environment
2. Building procedure
3. Compiler bug
4. Too complex source code / project structure

In most complex cases like yours all factors plays together, so trying to isolate causes one by one might help, or at least might show additional / new errors which will be easier to fix and proceed.

**Building environment**

You can try to build the same project on some other machine, or others machines (saying build I mean solving your task - publish website from command line). If you will have the same issues - it shows nothing, but if other environments are OK (or at least one of them) - then you definitely have an issue with environment.

It can be anything - .Net version and / or fixes, OS version, PATH variables for command line use incorrect framework, spaces in path for your local project - whatever, but if you can make it work on other machine, when you will know that you need to look into building process and not into other stuff.

You can try building any sample project just to ensure you can publish simple project.

**Building procedure**

Looks like you already isolated that issue is in publish step, but you can try to play with it a little - do only compilation without publishing, or run publish target over existing binaries / publish folder etc - you need to try to isolate particular step (if any) which fails, excluding dependencies on other build steps.

Most probably this won't help, as I expect that process fails as a whole - but who knows.

**Compiler bug**

This one is closely related to the next one. You can try, if it is possible in your case, to build on VS2012 instead of VS2013.

**Too complex source code / project structure**

Pre-build all the projects in solution, and use reference to resulted DLL instead of reference to projects. If everything OK - return project sources one by one, so that you can understand at least which project causes compiler to fail.

When/if you have isolated a project, then you can try to compile parts of it as separate DLL, and in some cases you might realize that some particular code constructions / markup should be rewritten to satisfy compiler.

If issue is in web project or in some other project type, which simply could not be compiled as single DLL, you can try to "turn off" whole parts of project - like, exclude several folders with web pages and check results.

Hope this helps, but for sure all these steps require significant efforts to just isolate the issue; but in most cases having the particular issue isolated solves a significant part of a problem.

Comment: Got dragged to another project but will pick this up again soon.  I have a simple project, but complex solution.  I'll try to simplify further and see if I can narrow it down to specific files, references, etc.  I haven't tried building on another machine yet, but definitely a good idea.  Building without publishing works as expected.  In fact, publishing without the precompilation also works.  Once I have more time to get back on this I'll divide and conquer.  If any of your suggestions help I'll give you the points.

Comment: Alright, so it looks like the new computer fixed the issue.  I'm no longer getting these errors with the same configs.  It's one of the first things you mentioned which I hadn't tried before so you finally get your bounty.  :)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but just in case someone will find this usefull:

The cause of this problem for me was the McAfee anti-virus

[ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error ASPRUNTIME: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838946/aspnetcompiler0-0-error-aspruntime-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-o/26883912#26883912)

Comment: You may be onto something.  My old computer with the issue and my new computer without the issue both have McAfee anti-virus.  Since it's no longer happening maybe some setting is different now, but at least we had that in common.

Comment: To me it was enough to exclude
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`
and
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\`
(I suppose you can narrow this down a bit further)
From McAfee scanning

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `-u` option should work, as it worked for me.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I tried both updateable and not.  From my question, the log showed `Task Parameter:Updateable=False (TaskId:2474)`.  I should be back on this project in about two weeks and I have a different computer now so I should have some updates then.

Comment: I have verified they weren't marked as updateable so this didn't apply to my case.