# ASPRUNTIME: The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, gulp

We're running Jekins which kicks off a gulp build process. As part of the gulp build process we trigger an [msbuild task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-msbuild).

Every second build fails with the message:

> ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.

This happens exactly every other build no matter the time span between builds. (i.e. Builds, Fails, Builds, Fails).

Any ideas on what might be causing this and why it happens only every other build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We solved this problem by allocating more memory to the build machine.

Comment: Thanks to this answer i tried to close unnecessary applications and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 11):

I also had this problem on a machine with enough memory. Turns out the problem was due to the target folder being Compressed using NTFS compression.

Once compression was disabled it started working without problems.

I saw that this could be a problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958884/83169.).

Comment: Had the same problem. (Jenkins and via `cmd.exe`.) Interestingly it worked if I called `aspnet_compiler.exe` (via `cmd.exe`) directly the same way as MSBuild does. But if run via MSBuild it failed. Otherwise not. Go figure!  
Somehow related: Never ever compress stuff where MS SQL Server stores it's database files.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but for googlers:
I had a similar problem when doing a build in visual studio. Turns out Dropbox was locking the compiled dlls. Once I'd excluded the bin directories (did obj directories too for good measure) the problem went away. This may also be the case for antivirus/antimalware programs too.

Comment: This is still a problem; literally just ran into this same thing via VS2019 (on 2020.11.22).

Answer (score 0):

The same error in my case was fixed by disabling memory compression.

I ran in elevated power shell

```
Disable-MMAgent -mc
```

and reboot

(Can be re enabled by `Enable-MMAgent -mc`)