# ms build throwing error ( for docker only)

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, msbuild, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows

. MY DOCKERFILE

```
FROM .....

SHELL ["powershell"]

RUN mkdir  'C:\\build\\'



COPY "./sys32/oledlg.dll" "C:\\Windows\\System32"
COPY "./syso64/oledlg.dll" "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64"
ADD . 'C:\\build\\'
WORKDIR 'C:\\build\\'

RUN Start-Process CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_16.msi -ArgumentList '/quiet', '/NoRestart' -Wait

RUN ["nuget.exe", "restore"]

RUN ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe", "C:\\build\\BrandIntell.sln"]


CMD ["powershell"]
```

. ERROR = `error ASPRUNTIME: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
  object`

. everything is working fine on local even the docker file is running fine but when doing it on the windows server 2016 , ec2 instance ,, it is throwing error while doing ms build using dockerfile

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838946/aspnetcompiler0-0-error-aspruntime-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-o

Comment: i unistalled antivirus also ,, then also not working . error occurs only when i try to ms build using dockerfile ,,not locally .

Comment: . when i run that dockerfile in my laptop ,, everything is working fine ..but when i try to do it on windows server 2016 ec2 instance with the same code ,,error occurs in ms build